# How can I get a faster connection on a saturated public network?

Tags: wireless-networking, download, speed

I'm working on a shared 8mbps connection in a public place, and I'm only getting 10KB/s because I believe the network is saturated with the other users downloading.

Is there a way I can get a better connection speed for myself under these circumstances?

Comment: This is better than your other question - thanks for making an effort - but please note that we *do not* accept re-posting the same question, even if the original is closed. I'll let it slip this once (and have deleted the original) but please don't re-post in the future.

Comment: switch to linux

Comment: @Shark: and _how_ exactly would it help?

Comment: @Shark, Really? While Windows does have some background processes (windows update, etc) the effect is probably not enough to have an impact (and certainly not enough to warrant a OS change).

Comment: I had a similar setup a while back and had experienced a better browsing/downloading  experience when I switched to  linux from windows (have no experience of OSx ) @tombull89 you probably listed the reasons

Comment: There is nothing you can do except find another connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really.  However, there are some ways you could speed up your web browsing.

- Increase the size of your browser cache - This will make loading web pages faster, because you're storing parts of the page on your computer rather than on the server
- Install add-ons that will block ads and other unnecessary things, such as [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/) and [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/).

Another option if you are in range of another public network but get a poor signal, is to build a [Cantenna](http://www.turnpoint.net/wireless/cantennahowto.html).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the Opera browser. I have the same problem in third world countries.  The newest, 11.11 has a turbo accelerator. After years of development, it finally works well. Also consider your own dns server if the dns is overloaded. There is a free windows product called treewalk DNS. You can install it on an old machine.